# Highchart / Highstock how to set color of individual ohlc or candle?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have set up a [highstock ohlc](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/ohlc) with angular 2. But can not set the up and down color for OHLC chart type, for example, green when hclose is increasing and red when it is decreasing. is there any API reference for that or any way to implement? like this below image I want my chart to look like.. [image: I want to implement something like this]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way like this and its working :-)

```
plotOptions: {
    ohlc: {
        color: 'red',
        upColor: 'green'
     }
},
series : [{   
    type: 'ohlc',                 
    name : 'Stock Price', 
    data : [],
    yAxis : 0,                            
}, {   
    type: 'column',                 
    name : 'volume', 
    data : [],
    yAxis : 1,                        
}]
```

Comment: The upColor property should have 'green' value and color should be 'red'. I prepared a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6orvqbLn/.

Comment: oops..I misplaced the color. Yes green should be the up color.. thnx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use these to change the colors for down line and up line colors as well.

```
plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
        color: 'red',
        upColor: 'green'
        lineColor: 'red',
        upLineColor: 'green'
    }
}
```